# add an Action Button in the currentView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.6

I'm beginner in objective-c and i don't find a solution on internet about my problem.

I'm trying to add a new action to a Button and it doesn't work.
Indeed i have more views in all the Views excepted the first View, i can't add this action to a button.
I work with Interface Builder to design my graphical View.

And if i want to add action to a button of the 2,3rd .. View by linking the button to ViewController.h, i can't
It's the same if i want to link the button to UIViewController.h, I have an error message which tell:
**Could not insert new action connection: No @implementation found for the class "UIViewController"**

i want to do that for example, if a user click on this button i will change the background color of the current View.

Another Question:

I don't know how to know what the current view is, for example if i want to change the color of the current view what i have to do ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not insert new action connection: No @implementation found for
>   the class "UIViewController"

**Answer :** Make sure you have your `ViewController.m` file in the project and that it has block starting with `@implementation` and ending with `@end`.

> I don't know how to know what the current view is, for example if i
>   want to change the color of the current view what i have to do ?

**Answer :**    `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]] works for the first View and second but not for the third because i can't add an action button to the second View ,I just add button and link him to the third view but i don't know when the user click on him.

The ViewController.m seems to be right. he is attached to my project and i have already create button action for the first View.

Comment: @user2466134 : It's really hard to understand what you are trying to say but if you satisfied with the Answer then check that Tick and mark it as "Accepted".

Comment: sorry but i don't speak english and i can't add image to show what my problem is but thanks.